# Prettier & Angular 15.1 : Only void and foreign elements can be self closed

Tags: angular, prettier

I'm using the one of feature of Angular 15.1 : self-closing tags but prettier is throwing :

```
Only void and foreign elements can be self closed
```

I'm on prettier 2.7.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The support of self-closing tags with Angular has landed with [Prettier 2.8.3](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/releases/tag/2.8.3).